How to Implement Custom Navigation Rail in Flutter App Bar?
I'm relatively new to Flutter and I'm currently developing a music app. I've designed a specific layout for the app bar and navigation rail on the home page, and I'm struggling to implement it in Flutter.
Now I have the app bar, but I want to add the navigation bar as seen in the picture.
Design Image:Link to Design
Is this design possible in Flutter? Because I didn't find any way to accomplish this.\
Home Page :Look to home_screen
home_screen code:-
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:aurora_music_v01/screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:version/version.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  late bool isDarkMode;
  bool isWelcomeBackVisible = true;
  bool isAuroraMusicVisible = false;
  User? user;
  Version? latestVersion;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1500), () {
      setState(() {
        isWelcomeBackVisible = false;
      });
    });

    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2500), () {
      setState(() {
        isAuroraMusicVisible = true;
      });
    });
    
    checkForNewVersion();
  }

  Future<void> checkForNewVersion() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('api_github_link'));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        final versionString = data['tag_name'];
        final regex = RegExp(r'^v?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+(-\S+)?)$');
        final match = regex.firstMatch(versionString);
        if (match!= null && match.groupCount > 0) {
          final versionString = match.group(1)!;
          setState(() {
            latestVersion = Version.parse(versionString);
          });
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error fetching latest version: $e');
    }
  }

  void launchURL(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      try {
        await launch(url);
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error launching URL: $e');
      }
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    isDarkMode = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final regex = RegExp(r'^v?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(-[a-zA-Z]+)?$');
    final match = regex.firstMatch('v0.0.5-alpha');
    final currentVersion = Version.parse(match!.group(1)!);
    final isUpdateAvailable = latestVersion!= null && latestVersion!.compareTo(currentVersion) > 0;

    if (isUpdateAvailable) {
      Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: const Text('New version available'),
              content: const Text('A new version of Aurora Music is available. Would you like to download it now?'),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: const Text('Cancel'),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                    await launch('github_link');
                  },
                  child: const Text('Download'),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      });
    }

    return user == null
       ? LoginPage()
        : Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage(isDarkMode
                       ? 'assets/images/background/dark_back.jpg'
                        : 'assets/images/background/light_back.jpg'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                elevation: 0.0,
                toolbarHeight: 230,
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                title: Center(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      AnimatedOpacity(
                        opacity: isWelcomeBackVisible? 1.0 : 0.0,
                        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                        child: const Text(
                          ' Welcome Back',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Outfit',
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 34,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                        ),
                      ),
                      AnimatedOpacity(
                        opacity: isAuroraMusicVisible? 1.0 : 0.0,
                        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                        child: const Text(
                          '   Aurora Music',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Outfit',
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 34,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
             ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),
              const Center(
                child: Text(
                  'App is under construction. Come back later!',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Outfit',
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Log out',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Outfit',
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 123, 14, 213),
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
  }
}



Please provide only the relevant part of your code or a minimal example of your issue.

Why don't you use Row for it with mainAxisAlignment as spaceEvenly. And design each item according to your need. Or use tabbar with custom tab widget.

to get such output  write the welcome back in the container and do it in Row widget give it MainAxisalignment: center and add a background color and font color you wish to the text and the for the below navigations use should use this kind of code (code for example)
body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 5, // Add one more tab for the RoadMap
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment:
              CrossAxisAlignment.start, // Align tabs to the start
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, // Align tabs to the start
          children: [
            TabBar(
              tabAlignment: TabAlignment.center,
              isScrollable: true,
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: 'Index'),
                Tab(text: 'Programs'),
                Tab(text: 'RoadMap'),
                Tab(text: 'Interview'),
                Tab(text: 'Description'),
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  IndexPage(),
                  ProgramsPage(),
                  RoadMapPage(),
                  InterviewPage(),
                  DescriptionPage(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],

and if you want to create the same as displayed in the image then you first use sizedbox  to give space between welocom back container and this navigations, then in the row widget write the text for discover then for "For You " use button style it by giving it border radius " borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0) ", and for other two use container and give MainAxisAllignment:spacearound to add space displayed in the image
